# Sympy performance issue with solving exp related equation

Tags: sympy

I have an equation: `f = (100*E**(-x*1600)-50)`, it takes a very long time to give a solution for `x` but in another [online solver](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=50%3D100*Power%5Be%2C-x*1600%5D), it only takes a few ms. How can I do to boost the performance?

raw code:

```
f = (100*E**(-x*1600)-50)
solve(f,x)
```

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: You really need to learn how to write questions. What is `lam`? what are you trying to solve? You mentioned an online solver was able to solve it, please post the link. We want to help, but...

Comment: @Davide_sd, Sorry for that, updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the real solution (and not the many symbolic solutions) use `nsolve`. The `bisect` solvers is appropriated for this function with a steep gradient near the root. Defining `lam = var('lam')` gives

[image]

If you want a symbolic solution (but not the many imaginary ones) then `solveset` or the lower level `_invert` can be used:

```py
>>> from sympy import solveset, var, Reals
>>> from sympy.solvers.solvers import _invert
>>> var('x')
x
>>> eq=(100*E**(-x*1600)-50)
>>> solveset(eq,x,Reals)
{log(2)/1600}
>>> from sympy.solvers.solvers import _invert
>>> _invert(eq,x)
(log(2)/1600, x)
```

Comment: Hi @smichr, How about I want real? Updated question...

Comment: I mean many symbolic solutions.